# Error returning values based on date range Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a query to bring values ​​of the last 5 years of each month, 
it works until you arrive in a few months that has a 
different last day (like 31 or 29)

```
   SELECT isin, nominal_comulativo , periodo_base
   FROM lamina_perfil
   WHERE isin = 'PERFIL 2020'
   AND periodo_base >= date '2019-03-31' - INTERVAL '5 years'
   AND periodo_base <=  '2019-03-31'
```

My result appears something like this

```
+----------------+--------------------+--------------+
|     ISIN       | nominal_comulativo | periodo_base |
+----------------+--------------------+--------------+
| PERFIL 2020    | 1.04               | 2014-03-31   |
+----------------+--------------------+--------------+
| PERFIL 2020    | 2.45               | 2014-04-30   |
+----------------+--------------------+--------------+
| PERFIL 2020    | 1.34               | 2014-05-30   |
+----------------+--------------------+--------------+
| PERFIL 2020    | 1.34               | 2014-06-30   |
+----------------+--------------------+--------------+
| PERFIL 2020    | 1.34               | 2014-07-31   |
+----------------+--------------------+--------------+
| PERFIL 2020    | 1.34               | 2014-08-29   |
+----------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

But when I set the WHERE condition different, like

```
period_base> = date '2019-02-31' - INTERVAL '5 years'
AND period_base <= '2019-02-31'
```

It gives me the error 'date / time field value out of range: "2019-02-31"'
**someone else?**

Comment: "2019-02-31", Feb 31, is not a valid date. Feb has 28 or 29 days, only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres is quite flexible about understanding date intervals, so you could express your conditions as follows:

```
periodo_base >= date'2019-04-01' - interval '1 day 5 years'
and periodo_base <=  date'2019-04-01' - interval '1 day'
```

This can be shortened a bit with `between`:

```
periodo_base 
    between date'2019-04-01' - interval '1 day 5 years' 
    and date'2019-04-01' - interval '1 day'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table is not very big, then how about:

```
SELECT isin, nominal_comulativo, periodo_base
FROM lamina_perfil
WHERE isin = 'PERFIL 2020' AND
      DATE_TRUNC('month', periodo_base) = '2019-03-01' AND
      periodo_base >= DATE_TRUNC('year', now()) - INTERVAL '5 year'
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer half-open intervals

---

```
SELECT isin, nominal_comulativo , periodo_base
FROM lamina_perfil
WHERE isin = 'PERFIL 2020'
AND periodo_base >= date '2019-04-01' - INTERVAL '5 years'
AND periodo_base < '2019-04-01'
```